# upgrade ubuntu and also install layer of gui on it(on server version)

Tags: command-line, 10.04, gui

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and i want to upgrade it to 12.04.

What do i do?

I know from my friend that Ubuntu 10.04 server has been outdated, but I have only the 10.04 CD.I also got to know that the server versions don't have a GUI, so I wanted help.
Is it okay to use 12.04 server version? I mean it isn't outdated yet right?

I also want to know how I can install a layer of GUI on it
(because i have server version)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 Server is not outdated. Actually it's supported until April 2015. To get more recent package versions you should upgrade, though, or better yet, reinstall from scratch to avoid any upgrade issues.

To upgrade, first make absolutely sure you have a good backup of everything, then execute the do-release-upgrade command and follow the instructions.

As for the GUI part, you can install it by installing the ubuntu-desktop package, or for a lighter version xubuntu-desktop.

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```